# Does the TFS Rest API support gzip encoding?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

This is the REST API used to connect with Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), and on-premise TFS. I would like to set the headers so I can compress my requests, but the API documentation does not specify that gzip is supported. I'm hoping somebody might have experience.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Credentials = TfsCredentials;
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding] = "gzip";
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var gzipByteArray = GZipBytes(serializedJson);
    var uploadResponse = wc.UploadData(repoUri, gzipByteArray);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uploadResponse);
}
```

Response is a 400, with the following error message:

```
The body of the request contains invalid Json. Parameter name: contentStream
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any documentation about this either. But I tested it with and without gzip compress from curl. The size of response is indeed compressed with gzip and the response can be decompressed correctly. So it should be supported.
[image]

Comment: Good enough for me! Can't wait to try it out.

Comment: It looks like you are correct for getting gzipped responses. However, I am trying to gzip an upload to the server. Apologies, I unaccepted the answer. I am also updating the question with my results so far.

Comment: @AJMorris Can you try with "Content-Encoding: gzip"? And you should also keep "Content-Type: application/json“ in the header since the content you sent is still  application/json.

Comment: Thanks @Eddie. That's what I actually had, but I typed it differently. Updated question to include the actual code. It seems like the TFS server is not checking that header, and just trying to deserialize the byte array as a JSON string. Just conjecture.